# extending the security role entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to extend the security role entity to include some custom permissions relating to my business.
For instance, I might want to add things like 'Can approve an order of up to X $' or 'can update leads whose name begins with Y' (just some examples, of course).
I will then use these permissions in workflows, plugins and iframes which I will develop.

I haven't found a good way to do it- as far as I can tell, the `security role` entity is not customizable, so I can't add any fields to it.
I thought about creating a custom entity `Role exstension` which will hold this data for me and will have a 1:1 relationship with `security role`. However, I haven't been able to find a way to create a relationship with the `role` entity.

Anyone has any thoughts?

Comment: What about adding it to SystemUser or Team rather than role?

Answer (score 0):

You are right you cannot extend the security role entity. I would recommend setting up a new entity called “Role Extension” (as you mentioned) and relating it to either a user directly or a team with a N:N relationship type. You could then use the built in CRM subgrids or a small Silverlight part to manage the roles

Comment: Hence the as (you) mentioned part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement this kind of functionality quite nicely with plugins. Using plugins embeds the rules into the pipeline and ensures if you are using the SDK, they will be implemented.

e.g. enforce rule that only users with Role 'My Custom Sales Role' can approve order of more than 5 products

- Create plugin that runs on order status change
- Detect if quantity is > 5
- If not, carryon
- If so, get executing user guid
- Retrieve user roles
- Check for 'My Custom Sales Role'
- Allow action if exists, if not throw exception 'You do not have permissions blah blah'

This keeps your rules in one place (a single library can encapsulate all rules). It does depend a bit on how many you have, but keeping them in the pipeline sounds like a reasonable approach to me.